# how to inject javascript for loop in selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium

i'm encountering some problems with executing java script for loop into selenium script. Probably there is something wrong with syntax. Basicaly the goal is to inject loop which repeats 10x and clicks the button, followed with 2 sec delay.

```
 submit = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']//form//div[3]//div[@class='button-row']//button[1]")))
                if submit:
                    submit.click()
                    time.sleep(self.random_number)
                    try:
                        self.browser.execute_script("""
                        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                                    document.querySelector("button[id='wyszukaj'").click();
                                },2000);}""")
                    except:
                        print("do nothin
```

g")

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to execute javascript code when the same can be accomplished in python?

```
submit = WebDriverWait(self.browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']//form//div[3]//div[@class='button-row']//button[1]")))
                if submit:
                    submit.click()
                    time.sleep(self.random_number)
                    try: 
                        for i in range(10):
                            my_button = WebDriverWait(self.browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "wyszukaj")))
                            my_button.click()
                            time.sleep(2)                            
                    except:
                        print("do nothing")
```

Comment: already resolved ;) Yeah I finally did it on python. I thoguht it wouldn't obtain the same effect, but hopefully it worked ;)